# Replace recursion in a randomized binary search tree with a loop?

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, binary-search-tree

I have a tree code using recursion:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

struct TreeNode {
    int value;
    int size;
    std::vector<TreeNode*> children;

    TreeNode(int val) : value(val), size(1), children(2, nullptr) {}
};

class RandomizedBinarySearchTree {
private:
    TreeNode* root;

    int getSize(TreeNode* node) {
        return node ? node->size : 0;
    }

    TreeNode* rotateRight(TreeNode* p) {
        if (p->children[0] == nullptr) return p;

        TreeNode* q = p->children[0];
        p->children[0] = q->children[1];
        q->children[1] = p;
        q->size = p->size;
        fixSize(p);
        return q;
    }

    TreeNode* rotateLeft(TreeNode* q) {
        if (q->children[1] == nullptr) return q;

        TreeNode* p = q->children[1];
        q->children[1] = p->children[0];
        p->children[0] = q;
        p->size = q->size;
        fixSize(q);
        return p;
    }

    TreeNode* insertRoot(TreeNode* p, int k) {
        if (!p) return new TreeNode(k);
        if (k < p->value) {
            p->children[0] = insertRoot(p->children[0], k);
            return rotateRight(p);
        }
        else {
            p->children[1] = insertRoot(p->children[1], k);
            return rotateLeft(p);
        }
    }

public:
    void fixSize(TreeNode* node) {
        if (node) {
            node->size = getSize(node->children[0]) + getSize(node->children[1]) + 1;
        }
    }

    RandomizedBinarySearchTree() : root(nullptr) {}

    ~RandomizedBinarySearchTree() {
        
    }

    void insert(int val) {
        root = insertRecursive(root, val);
    }

    TreeNode* insertRecursive(TreeNode* node, int val) {
        if (!node) {
            return new TreeNode(val);
        }

        if (rand() % (getSize(node) + 1) == 0) {
            return insertRoot(node, val);
        }

        if (val < node->value) {
            node->children[0] = insertRecursive(node->children[0], val);
        }
        else {
            node->children[1] = insertRecursive(node->children[1], val);
        }

        fixSize(node);
        return node;
    }

    void unionTrees(RandomizedBinarySearchTree& other) {
        root = unionRecursive(root, other.root);
    }

    TreeNode* unionRecursive(TreeNode* nodeA, TreeNode* nodeB) {
        if (!nodeB) {
            return nodeA;
        }

        nodeA = unionRecursive(nodeA, nodeB->children[0]);
        nodeA = unionRecursive(nodeA, nodeB->children[1]);
        nodeA = insertRoot(nodeA, nodeB->value);

        fixSize(nodeA);
        return nodeA;
    }

    TreeNode* getRoot() const {
        return root;
    }

    void printPreOrder(TreeNode* node) {
        if (node) {
            std::cout << node->value << " ";
            printPreOrder(node->children[0]);
            printPreOrder(node->children[1]);
        }
    }

    void printInOrder(TreeNode* node) {
        if (node) {
            printInOrder(node->children[0]);
            std::cout << node->value << " ";
            printInOrder(node->children[1]);
        }
    }

    void printTree(TreeNode* node, int space = 0) {
        const int count = 5;

        if (!node) {
            return;
        }

        space += count;

        printTree(node->children[1], space);

        std::cout << std::endl;
        for (int i = count; i < space; i++) {
            std::cout << " ";
        }
        std::cout << " \\" << node->value << "\n";

        printTree(node->children[0], space);
    }


    class Iterator {
    private:
        TreeNode* current;
        std::vector<TreeNode*> ancestors;

    public:
        Iterator(TreeNode* node) : current(node) {
            // Move to the leftmost node to start an in-order traversal
            while (current) {
                ancestors.push_back(current);
                current = current->children[0];
            }
        }

        // Overload the dereference operator
        int operator*() const {
            return ancestors.back()->value;
        }

        // Overload the pre-increment operator (++it)
        Iterator& operator++() {
            if (!ancestors.empty()) {
                current = ancestors.back()->children[1];
                ancestors.pop_back();

                // Move to the leftmost node of the right child
                while (current) {
                    ancestors.push_back(current);
                    current = current->children[0];
                }
            }
            return *this;
        }

        // Overload the not-equal-to operator (!=)
        bool operator!=(const Iterator& other) const {
            return !ancestors.empty() || !other.ancestors.empty();
        }
    };


    // Iterator begin() method
    Iterator begin() const {
        return Iterator(root);
    }

    // Iterator end() method
    Iterator end() const {
        return Iterator(nullptr);
    }

};

int main() {
    srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(0)));

    RandomizedBinarySearchTree treeA;
    RandomizedBinarySearchTree treeB;

    treeA.insert(10);
    treeA.insert(5);
    treeA.insert(15);

    treeB.insert(20);
    treeB.insert(25);
    treeB.insert(22);

    std::cout << "Tree A (pre-order): ";
    treeA.printPreOrder(treeA.getRoot());
    treeA.printTree(treeA.getRoot());
    std::cout << "\nTree B (in-order): ";
    treeB.printInOrder(treeB.getRoot());
    treeB.printTree(treeB.getRoot());

    std::cout << "\n\nTree A + Tree B (pre-order): ";
    treeA.unionTrees(treeB);
    treeA.printPreOrder(treeA.getRoot());

    std::cout << "\n\nTree A + Tree B (symbolic representation): \n";
    treeA.printTree(treeA.getRoot());

    std::cout << "\n\nIterating through the merged tree using iterator: ";
    for (auto it = treeA.begin(); it != treeA.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

It is necessary to replace the recursion with a loop. I tried to do this through a pointer to parent in the insertroot method, as a result, not all elements were in the output.

Tell me how to replace it with a loop, at least using the example of insertroot.

Comment: Short of homework requirements, do you actually need to replace recursion with a loop?  Think about how a balanced binary tree works. Picking any given branch eliminates half of the possibilities. Inserting into a binary tree with 10 _million_ nodes should only require ~23-24 recursive calls. This is unlikely to blow up your stack. 10 _billion_ nodes? Around 29-30 recursive calls.

Comment: Unfortunately, the task requires a replacement

Comment: I don't see any attempt at an iterative implementation. This provided code does not have the problem you describe. There should be no problem with an iterative algorithm; it has been provided many times, like on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Iterative_search)

Comment: Are you searching an unordered binary tree or a sorted / balanced binary tree?  Searching a binary tree of randomly ordered data is not efficient.

Comment: The good thing about this assignment is you know it will have a solution : Any recursive algorithm can be converted to an iterative one (and vice versa)

Comment: I understand this is a homework. But otherwise recursion in this situation makes perfect sense, and is much easier than iterative way that would require some manual stack. My rule: *the maximum recursion depth for a recursive function shall be **O(log n)***. Having a **O(n)** depth is asking for trouble: it will quickly crash with (not so) big `n`.

Comment: You need a **threaded binary tree** implementation. Simple binary trees are not suitable for iterative algorithms.

Comment: Here is one of the attempts to redo it into a cycle. but then some elements are missing from the output, as if they are being lost.
``
TreeNode* insertRoot(TreeNode* p, int k) {
    TreeNode* newNode = new TreeNode(k);

    


while (p) {
        if (k < p->value) {
            p->children[0] = rotateRight(p->children[0]);
            p = p->children[0];
        }
        else {
            p->children[1] = rotateLeft(p->children[1]);
            p = p->children[1];
        }
    }

    return newNode;
}
``